# Set row that contains certain text as row number "x" - Excel/VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro running that begins with;

```
Sub (myMacro)
For a = 10 To 200

Cells(a, 2).Value = "Value for a"
Cells(a + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert

Next a
End Sub
```

Above is simplified for the purpose of this question.

On row 100 column B (before the macro) is the text "Important Notes". Once the macro runs, the cell with "Important Notes" becomes row 101.

The problem I have is that I need the macro to run from rows 10 up until the row that has "Important notes". I may add another 50 or 100 rows by using the macro (which inserts a new row each time), which is why I can't set "For a = 10 to 100".

Is there a way to somehow achieve the below (doesn't work) where x is the row number that contains "Important Notes"

```
For a = 10 to x
```

Thank you.

Comment: You want to insert blank row where the condition match. Before or after the specific word ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub InsertBlankRows()
    
    Dim Col         As Variant
    Dim BlankRows   As Long
    Dim LastRow     As Long
    Dim R           As Long
    Dim StartRow    As Long
    
    Col = "B"
    StartRow = 1
    BlankRows = 1
    
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = FALSE
    
    With ActiveSheet
        For R = LastRow To StartRow + 1 Step -1
            If .Cells(R, Col) = "Important Notes" Then
                .Cells(R, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            End If
        Next R
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = TRUE
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Gald to hear. [How do I accept an answer, and what are the rules?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) @lyaof